# Mask rotates automatically when applied to rotated object

Tags: apache-flex, masking, rotatetransform

I have the following problem: I draw a shape on a Group, to be used as a mask. I then rotate an Image in x, y, z, using Rotate3D, and use the Group as the Image's mask, but the result is not what I want, because once the Group becomes the mask of the Image, it acquires its rotation too.
What I want to achieve, is to get a portion of a rotated Image, according to the shape that I have drawn. How can I apply the mask, whithout it be also rotated? Or can this be done any other way?

Here is the code:

```
    grpMask = new Group();
    g = grpMask.graphics;
    g.lineStyle(0, 0x00FF00);
    g.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
    g.beginFill(0x00FF00, .3);
    for (var i:int; i < points.length - 1; i++)
    {
       g.lineTo(points[i + 1].x, points[i + 1].y);
    }
    g.endFill();
    grpCanvas.addElement(grpMask);
```

I then set `imgTarget.mask = grpMask`. To imgTarget, have been applied several Rotate3D effects, which unfortunately pass on to the mask.

Comment: How about doing something like this: Put the object that is rotated in a container, then apply the mask to the container.

Comment: This, _did_ do the job. Thanks, Sunil D.! Please, answer this question normally, so that I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to add the object being rotated to a container class like a `Sprite` or a `Group`. Then apply the mask to the container, instead of the rotated object:

```
var container:Group = new Group();
container.addElement(roatatedObject);
container.mask = maskObject;
container.addElement(maskObject);
```

or

```
var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
container.addChild(rotatedObject);
container.mask = maskObject;
container.addChild(maskObject);
```